# Filtering has many relationship by value on the join table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a standard self referencing relationship for a User model representing friends.  That part works fine, but I have an extra column in the join table representing the source of that relationship.

Friendship Model

```
# Relationships
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
has_one :source
```

User Model

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :class_name => "User", :through => :friendships
```

I understand that I can do a where filter on my user's friends

```
 user.friends.where([some conditions])
```

My question is, how do I get a list of user object "friends" filtered by the :source relationship in Friendship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out.  In case anyone was curious.

User Model

```
 has_many :friendships
 has_many :friends, :class_name => "User", :through => :friendships do 
    def bySource(sourceId)
       where("friendships.source_id = ?", sourceId)
    end
 end
```

Usage

```
 users.friends.bySource(1)
```

Comment: You don't even have to do that.  You can place a scope on the friendships model called `by_source` and call it in exactly the same way.

Comment: That sounds great, I could define a scope by each source.  Can I get an example of that?